# Swift, hide overflowing text

Tags: swift, uiview, uilabel, swift2

I have a label with a single character that I wish to be bigger than the UIView that it's a subview of. However, I need to hide the overflowing parts of the character.

For an example, this is the result I'm trying to achieve: 
[image]

Where the character/Icon is the tags in lighter green in the background

Like the above example I'm using the font called "fontawesome" and their icon set. However in Swift I havn't been able to find any options to hide the overflowing parts.

Here's the current code:

```
var actionBox = UIView()
var actionLabel = UILabel()
var actionIcon = UILabel()

// #actionBox
    actionBox.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    actionBox.backgroundColor = UIColor.formulaGreenColor()
    cellView.addSubview(actionBox)

    actionIcon.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    actionIcon.font = UIFont(name: "fontawesome", size: 80)
    actionIcon.text = ""
    actionIcon.textColor = UIColor.colorWithHex("#13E6A7")
    actionBox.addSubview(actionIcon)
```

I know I can technically make another 2 UIViews, with a background color, and layer those on top. But that's not exactly an elegant solution.

So how can I hide the rest of the label, that's overflowing it's superView?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are searching for `clipsToBounds` property:

`view.clipsToBounds = true`

Where `view` is your container view.

Comment: This worked perfectly! thank you so much! Just a small correction, it's `.clipsToBounds = true` not `clipToBounds`